# How to execute two function according to a table result with a condition by using mssql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

`ParseValuesJson` and `insertToTable` are user defined function.

The following is the result of the execution ( `ParseValuesJson` ) :

```
declare 
    @json nvarchar(max)=N'{
    "Book":{
        "IssueDate":"02-15-2019"
        , "Detail":{
            "Type":"Any Type"
            , "Author":{
                "Name":"Annie"
                , "Sex":"Female"
            }
        }
        , "Chapter":[
            {
                "Section":"1.1"
                , "Title":"Hello world."
            }
            ,
            {
                "Section":"1.2"
                , "Title":"Be happy."
            }       
        ]
        , "Sponsor":["A","B","C"]
    }
}'

declare 
    @tempTable table (
        topKey nvarchar(4000)
        , [key] nvarchar(4000)
        , IsType bit
        , IsList bit
        , [value] nvarchar(4000))

--execute
insert @tempTable  
select * from GetValuesJson(@json,default)
```

```
topKey  Key         isType  isList  Value
--
Book    Type        0       0       Any Type
Book    Author      1       0       {"Name":"Annie", "Sex":"Female"}
Book    IssueDate   0       0       02-15-2019
Book    Chapter     1       1       [{"Section":"1.1", "Title":"Hello world."}, {"Section":"1.2", "Title":"Be happy."}]
Book    Sponsor     1       1       ["A","B","C"]
```

As title, If ignore what the function doing, how can I achieve the following purpose?

If `IsType`=1 , I want to call function `ParseValuesJson`;
If `IsType`=0 , I want to call function `insertToTable`.

But I found that sql `case` can not use like that.

This sql query may execute recursively and call different functions accordingly at the same level.

It means that I can't parse all string (`ParseValuesJson`) first and then insert the result (`insertToTable`) to the table.

Is there any other way to achieve?

```
select 
    case IsType when 1 then
        ParseValuesJson('{"' + [key] + '":' + [value] + '}',IsList)
    else
        insertToTable(topKey,[key])
    end
from ParseValuesJson(@json,default)
```

[image: concept]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest thing to do is to split it into two separate SELECTs.

```
select ParseValuesJson('{"' + [key] + '":' + [value] + '}',IsList)
from ParseValuesJson(@json,default)
where IsType = 1


select insertToTable(topKey,[key])
from ParseValuesJson(@json,default)
where IsType = 0
```

But I guess this approach won't help you since inside user defined functions you cannot use INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements -> i.e modify table data

So I guess that to parse the JSON you'd need to user recursive CTE to parse all values first and then to insert them into temp table at once.

Something like this:

```
;WITH ParsedJSON(topKey, [key], IsType, IsList, [value])
AS
(
SELECT topKey, [key], IsType, IsList, [value]
FROM ParseValuesJson('{"' + [key] + '":' + [value] + '}',IsList)

UNION ALL

SELECT topKey, [key], IsType, IsList, [value]
FROM ParsedJSON
WHERE IsType = 1
) 
insert @tempTable  
select * from ParsedJSON
```

Comment: But this sql query may execute repeatedly.

Comment: That is IMO OK. First select takes rows which have type 1 and calls for another parsing one level lower ( until tjat select returns 0 rows or all of type 0) and the second second select on the same level stores whichever row fell off as of type 0

Comment: I have extend the answer. Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, the expression is unclear. I have modified the question content.
I can't prase all string (`ParseValuesJson`) first and then insert the result (`insertToTable`) to the table .

Comment: Finally, I use Cursor to achieve my goal. Still thanks for your assistance